# Do intent based on which activity includes fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Hello i have made a fragment which has one button and I am using it in two activities. The problem which arises from this is that the fragment will do the same intent

Onclick(Type variable is which activity it should run and is not implemented into the onclick, this does not work):

```
runBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
if (type == 0){
        Intent sendToMain = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        sendToMain.putExtra("newStory", story);

    }
    if (type ==1){
        Intent reviewStoryIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),storyReviewActivity.class);
        reviewStoryIntent.putExtra("Story", story);
    }

        }
    });
```

Is there any way to differentiate between which activity the fragment is placed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your different activity as below in your fragment:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof YourFirstActivity) // type == 0
{
  // Do your stuff here for First Activity

}else if(getActivity() instanceof YourSecondActivity) // type ==1
{
  // Do your stuff here for Second Activity
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works! But is it also possible to putExtra an object from the current activity, i need to pass a Story object to either "yourFirstActivity" or "YourSecondActivity" @pRaNaY

Comment: No you can't pass `putExtra` in current activity. You can pass putExatra on target intent activity. If your current activity is `YourFirstActivity` then you can start intent of other activity with `putExtra`. As consider your code, If your current activity is `YourFirstActivity` (type==0) , then you can use `sendToMain` intent as you want. And If your current activity is `YourSecondActivity` (type==1) , then you can use `reviewStoryIntent` intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking on a different approach. What not to let your activities handle the intents?

So, your activities implements a callback method and your fragment call it so, every activity will know where that Intent should directed.

Hope it helps.